# Value of $(\cos a + \cos b)^2 + (\sin a + \sin b)^2 $ knowing that $a-b = \frac \pi6$ .

Tags: trigonometry

$$a-b = \frac \pi6$$
$$(\cos a + \cos b)^2 + (\sin a +  \sin b)^2 = ?$$
How do i solve this problem? I've tried to solve it on my book and got the answer is $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: What stops you expanding the terms?

Comment: "Solve it on my book ?"? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Why don't you answer my question ?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I took a shower.

Comment: I mean that my notebook. sorry for that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given
$$
 a - b = \frac{\pi}{6}  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad a = b + \frac{\pi}{6}
$$
Evaluate
$$
\left(\cos (a)+\cos (b))^2 + (\sin (a)+\sin (b)\right)^2
$$

---

**Cosine terms**

All pieces
$$
\left(\cos (a)+\cos (b)\right)^2 =  \cos ^2\left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)
+2 \cos (b) \cos \left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)
+\cos ^2(b)
$$

First quadratic
$$
\cos ^2\left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sin \left(2 b-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)
$$

Cross term
$$
2\cos (b) \cos \left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right) = 
\frac{1}{4} \left(2 \cos \left(2 b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)+\sqrt{3}\right)
$$

Last quadratic
$$
\cos ^2(b) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left(1  + \cos (2 b)\right)
$$

---

**Sine terms**

All pieces
$$
\left(\sin (a)+\sin (b)\right)^2 =  \sin ^2\left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)
+2 \sin (b) \sin \left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)
+\sin ^2(b)
$$

First quadratic
$$
\sin ^2\left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left(1  + \cos (2 b)\right)
$$

Cross term
$$
2\sin (b) \sin \left(b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-2 \cos \left(2 b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)
$$

Last quadratic
$$
\sin ^2(b) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \sin \left(2 b-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)
$$

---

**Combine terms**

$$
\left(\cos (a)+\cos (b))^2 + (\sin (a)+\sin (b)\right)^2 
= 2 + \sqrt{3}
$$

Comment: your answer is great. I understood!

Answer (score 0):

$(\cos a + \cos b)^2 + (\sin a +  \sin b)^2 = \cos^2 a + \cos^2 b + 2\cos a \cos b + \sin^2 a +  \sin^2 b + 2\sin a \sin b=(\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a) + (\cos^2 b + \sin^2 b) + 2(\cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b)=1 + 1 + 2 \cos (a-b)=2+2\cos \frac{\pi}{6}=2+2.\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=2+\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Because a basic formula of trigonometry says that $\cos^2 a +\sin^2 a=1$ for any $a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)^2+(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)^2=2+2\cos(\alpha-\beta)=2+\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\cos{a}+\cos{b})^2+(\sin{a}+\sin{b})^2 = 2 + 2(\cos{a}\cos{b}+\sin{a}\sin{b})= 2+2\cos({a-b}) = 2+\sqrt{3}$$